# Problema ao criar projeto

Tags: android

Toda vez que tento criar um projeto no Eclipse Luna para Android no Console da várias mensagens de erros. Eu já instalei o ADT e o SDK normal.

Agora não consigo mais fazer nada porque o projeto fica dando erro e nem compila sem erros mais.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Comment: Poderia mostrar uma dessas mensagens de erro?

Answer (score 2):

Use o `Android Studio` ele tem suporte total ao `Android` e é passível da utilização dos plugins da `Jetbrains`, o Google não fornece mais suporte ao `ADT` (plugin do eclipse para desenvolver Android), logo o `ADT` tende a não suportar as novas `APIs do Android` (que atualmente esta na revisão 22).

Nota sobre ADT:

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

Comment: Não precisa colocar formatação de código em coisas que não são código, como nomes de produtos. E, principalmente, evite editar postagens alheias para inserir isso. Ver http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas/1297#1297. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o erro para gente compreender melhor o que está acontecendo.  Mas,  como muitos já disseram,  é recomendado,  praticamente forçado xD ,  o uso do Android Studio para desenvolvimento dos aplicativos.  Eu particularmente recomendo e vejo imensas vantagens sobre o eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver seu problema teria que ser necessário ler as mensagens de erro que aparecem no seu console. Mas por via das duvidas, se você é um iniciante em desenvolvimento android, recomendo que comece a utilizar o Android Studio, pois o mesmo já a algum tempo é a IDE oficial para desenvolvimento em android e creio que nela não terá esses problemas.